# Eclipse: Issue displaying picture using HTML <img> tag

Tags: html, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to learn javascript. For some reason, I'm not able to make the picture display in the browser.

Guess I should be doing something wrong. but, can't figure it out exactly.

[image]

That's what I see in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Does your src generate a '404 Not found' or a '403 Forbidden' error in your access log?  404 means you've got the path wrong. 403 means you have the permissions wrong.

Comment: I uploaded another picture to make it more clear.

Comment: look in your access logs, or use Firebug with Firefox to see what errors are actually happening. The 'broken img' icon doesn't tell you *why* you can't see your pic.